# Roll up Count of booleans

Tags: formula, formula-field, roll-up-summary

Is it possible to use a roll up or formula field to count the number of "true" or "false" values on a boolean field of a detail record?

Example:

> **Account** <-*Master*-----*Detail*-> **My_Object__c**

**My_Object__c** has a boolean (checkbox) field called **My_Boolean__c**

I want to create a field on **Account** Object that will tell me how many of the child objects have **My_Boolean__c** set to false.

Is this possible without creating a trigger or workflow?

Answer (score 9):

As you spotted, this can be done declaratively in one fell swoop!

1. On the Master, create a **Roll-up Summary** called `CountMyBoolean__c` with `COUNT`
2. Under **Filter Criteria** choose 'records meeting certain criteria' and `MyBoolean__c equals True`

Comment: yea, I considered this.  I just wanted to check if there was a way to do skipping step one.  Guess one extra field won't hurt...

Comment: wait, can I use rollup with record count and do a filter on boolean_field = true?

Comment: Ah great spot - yes, you can use `Filter Criteria` in roll up summaries! Go with `COUNT()` instead.

Comment: yea, i should have just looked more into it first.  I was in the process of implementing your solution when I noticed

Comment: Remember the Apex Ten commandments. Thou shalt find a happy balance between clicks and code ( http://m.youtube.com/?#/watch?v=D7mqMYliy3A).

Comment: user320 strikes again! and @Francis manages to plug his presentation, again ;)

Comment: Well got to drum up interest for DF14 :)